# Not able to pass a list of elements using terraform0.11

Tags: terraform, terraform0.11

I am trying to pass a variable of type list as follow:

In the `cf-app.tf` file:

```
resource "cloudfoundry_app" "my-app" {

service_binding = "${var.service-bindings}"

}
```

In `variables.tf` file:

```
variable "service-bindings" {
  type = "list"
  default = []
}
```

In `deployment.tf` file:

```
module "nested-module" {
source = "../my-app"

  service-bindings = [
    {
      service_instance = "dummy1"
    },
    {
      service_instance = "dummy2"
    }
  ]

}
```

but I m getting the below error, this is a known `terraform 11` issue and has been fixed in `terraform 12`:

```
Error: module.nested-module.cloudfoundry_app.myapp: service_binding: should be a list
```

I followed [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121591/terraform-passing-list-through-modules-getting-error-should-be-a-list) but my challenge is with the string of elements...

I am currently using `terraform version 11`.

Can someone help me resolve this in a hacky way?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Any concrete reason you keep using 0.11? This version is very, very old.

Comment: We will be moving to terraform0.12 by end of this year.

Comment: If the issue you are facing is caused by your TF version, and it was fixed in newer releases, what exactly do you want to do? Backport the fixes?

Comment: "We will be moving to terraform0.12 by end of this year." You're going to update your version, so you've decided to move to a version that's already 4 major versions out of date? Why not move to v1.0 instead?

Comment: Due to cloud [foundry terraform provider](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/terraform-provider-cloudfoundry), we can only migrate to 0.12, thank everyone

Answer (score 1):

Terraform v0.11's type system does not support this sort of nested data structure. It supports only strings, lists of strings, and maps of strings.

Your example here is therefore combining various capabilities that Terraform v0.11 is not well-suited to support and that were exactly the sort of limitations that prompted the rewrite of the Terraform language for Terraform v0.12.

My best suggestion for your situation would be to discard the idea of factoring out `resource "cloudfoundry_app" "my-app"` into a shared module and instead write it directly as an inline resource with the settings you need specified directly inside:

```
resource "cloudfoundry_app" "my-app" {
  service_binding {
    service_instance = "dummy1"
  }

  service_binding {
    service_instance = "dummy2"
  }
}
```

Once you're ready to upgrade to a more modern version of Terraform, you can rewrite this as a `dynamic` block to generate multiple `service_binding` blocks based on your input variable, and *then* consider factoring it out into a separate module once you can use a sufficiently-expressive Terraform language version:

```
# This configuration is only for Terraform v0.12 or later

variable "service_bindings" {
  type = list(object({
    service_instance = string
    params_json      = string
  }))
}

resource "cloudfoundry_app" "my-app" {
  dynamic "service_binding" {
    for_each = var.service_bindings
    content {
      service_instance = service_binding.value.service_instance
      params_json      = service_binding.value.params_json
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have:

```
service_binding = "${var.service-bindings}"
```

When `var.service-bindings` is a list and the `service_binding` input expects a list? Shouldn't this be:

```
service_binding = var.service-bindings
```

I don't have Terraform v0.11 installed and I have no intention of installing it to test this, but you could try:

1. Removing `type = "list"` from your variable. Will it still throw this error if you don't ask it to validate that the type is correct?
2. Does 0.11 support the `jsonencode` function? If so, try:

```
resource "cloudfoundry_app" "my-app" {
  service_binding = jsondecode(var.service-bindings)
}

variable "service-bindings" {
  type = "string"
  default = "[]"
}
```

```
module "nested-module" {
  source = "../my-app"

  service-bindings = jsonencode([
    {
      service_instance = "dummy1"
    },
    {
      service_instance = "dummy2"
    }
  ])
}
```